# USB Hub powers down in sleep mode on Win 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-hub

I would like the USB hub to remain on in sleep so I can wake up the laptop from an external keyboard and mouse.

I have set all the device drivers by unchecking allow this device to be powered down and disabled selective suspend in control panel but the hub still powers down.

If I plug a keyboard or mouse directly in to the PC they remain powered and wake the computer its only when they are connected through the hub there is a problem.

I have another PC running Win 7 x86. If I set this up in exactly the same way the hub remains powered in sleep.

Both PC's are Toshiba Satellites with multi-core celerons but one runs Win 7 x86 the other Win 7 x64. BIOS settings are the same.